# Access database from broadcast?

Tags: android, sqlite, broadcastreceiver

Can I  access any database in the broadcast receiver? I want to get contact name from the contacts number inside the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only restriction is that you have 10 seconds timeout in Brodcast Reveiver. So it is advised that long going actions to be executed in started service/asyncTask.

Comment: thank you very much it was helpful
:)
can i get the contact name from his phone number when i press on the notification
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488771/android-get-contact-name-when-i-click-on-notification-icon-from-his-phone-numb

Comment: Please describe your problem in more details. ( link that you probided has been deleted).

Comment: Thanks but the answer was just perfect for me
:)

Comment: yes
but at that day it was not clear answer but after long searching i understood the answer and thanks for the help dude
:)